# Win32API Determine if the USB device is disconnected

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to monitor whether the handheld scanner (connected USB->COM6) is online or offline. `WM_DEVICECHANGE`: is structured as follows:

```
switch (wParam)
{
    case DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL:
        if (lpdb->dbch_devicetype == DBT_DEVTYP_PORT)
        {
            PDEV_BROADCAST_PORT_A lpdbv = (PDEV_BROADCAST_PORT_A)lpdb;
            if (strcmp(lpdbv->dbcp_name, "COM6") == 0)
            {
                MessageBox ...
            }
        } 
    break;
}
```

As long as the scanner is not running (thread not started), the messages arrive correctly. If the scanner is running, then the `DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL/DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE` messages will not arrive. Only `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED` messages are received.
But with `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED` it is not possible to determine a device type.

How else can I determine that the USB scanner was unplugged?

Comment: What does "USB->COM6" mean? Is it an USB scanner that is "visible" as COM port or do you connect the device using an USB-to-COM adapter?

Comment: Right. USB scanner, in RS232 mode, visible as COM6.

Comment: The scanner waits in the thread for EV_RXCHAR event (receive character).
It is enough to open the COM6 port with "CreateFile", and the plug-in/unplug messages are no longer received.

Comment: There are [samples of how to connect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/usbcon/how-to-write-a-windows-desktop-app-that-communicates-with-a-usb-device) for this.

Comment: Or how about [SetupDiEnumDeviceInterfaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/setupapi/nf-setupapi-setupdienumdeviceinterfaces) when `DBT_DEVNODES_CHANGED` is arrived?

Comment: Thank you very much. The problem was with the device drivers. As soon as you use generic drivers under Win10, everything works as expected. But as soon as you install the manufacturer's drivers, this problem occurs.